# I feel bad about accepting my own answer to my own question, what to do?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

I always think someone may answer something better or more updated.
Also accepting my own answer feels strange overall.
(unless my own answer is much more upvoted than other answers, like 10x, but I dont remember something like that happening)

The problem, is: that question (despite answered) remains not accepted (therefore not clear, to the reader, if the question problem was "acceptedly" dealt with).

Any considerations?

Comment: So don't accept it, and say in it that it works & is the best you've got so far but you hope for better.

Comment: thats what I sometimes say xD

Comment: There's no guarantee that the accepted answer is the best answer that will help others most. It's just the answer that will stay on top of everything else. When someone has a problem, they're likely to go through all the answers. Some even go through the answers from the bottom up :)

Answer (score 9):

There is no requirement to accept an answer. Acceptance is merely a signal from the original asker that the accepted answer was the one they found *most helpful*, and often implies that their problem is "resolved".

However, even if an answer has been accepted, the question is not closed. New answers are always allowed to be added, and users are encouraged to add new answers if they have a novel or better solution to the problem.

If you aren't happy with any of the answers, and/or you do not feel that any of them represent a good solution to your problem, then there is no rush to accept an answer.

At the same time, though, you should not feel any guilt about accepting your own answer. It often indicates that you did your own research and solved your problem—that's something to celebrate. In many cases, you're in the best position to judge what is the best answer to the question, since you're the one having the problem.

The only case where you should second-guess accepting your own answer is if someone else did the bulk of the work to get you to the solution. At that point, you should strongly consider rewarding them and highlighting their answer as the best solution. But even that's not a hard rule. If you truly feel that your self-answer is the best, most complete, most useful solution, then you should go ahead and accept it.

Of course, while accepts are limited to one-per-question, upvotes are not.